# Web log analyser with daily statistics per URL

Tags: web-server, log-files, logging

**Are there any good web server log analysis tools that can provide me with daily statistics on individual URLs?** I guess I'm looking at something that can drill down into particular URLs and on particular days rather than just a monthly summary report.

The following don't seem to meet my needs as they don't offer drilling down to get more detailed info:

- awstats
- analog
- webalizer

(I'm running an nginx frontend into Apache with nginx outputting 'combined' format logfiles if it makes any difference.)

Answer (score 1):

The most full-featured log analysis tool I've ever used was [Sawmill](http://www.sawmill.net/).  It isn't free, though it appears they have a demo version available.  Company I was at purchased it, so my only experience was with the licensed version, however based on your need to "drill down" you won't find anything as detailed as this.

The one down side (ignoring the cost factor), is the CPU- and IO-intensiveness of the product.  Obviously we ran through hundreds of gigabytes in our quest to analyze a few years worth of data, so YMMV.

While you're at it, Wikipedia has a list (including Sawmill) of similar, notable products available [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software).

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for GoogleAnalytics type of output you should take a look at:

- http://piwik.org/
- http://www.openwebanalytics.com/

I've used the first before and it did allowed me a good breath and depth of analysis. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a plugin for [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). Have a look at [github](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/contrib/tree/master/plugins).
And "howto" is here: github.com/perusio/nginx-munin